# Python replace javascript double quotes in javascript code

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web, driver

I am trying to get selenium webdriver to execute the following javascript

```
document.querySelector('#location > input[type="text"]').value="10001"
```

but when I use the

```
execute_script("document.querySelector('#location > input[type="text"]').value="10001"")
```

Because of the quotes, it fails to run, how to escape the quotes?

Comment: Single backslash `\"` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Use backslashes to escape quotes within quotes:

```
execute_script("document.querySelector('#location > input[type=\"text\"]').value = \"10001\"')
```

Btw, in this specific case you don't really need additional quotes. This will also work:

```
execute_script("document.querySelector('#location > input[type=text]').value = 10001')
```

Comment: yes because 1001 happens to be a number,I was actually concerned cause when I have to set the visibility it happens to be a string and it fails. Thanks a lot Sir

Comment: yes, that's why I said in this specific case, if it's a number it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using three quotes?

```
execute_script("""document.querySelector('#location > input[type="text"]').value="10001" """)
```

Comment: I tried " ' " code " ' " not straight triple occurrences of double quotes,I will try. Thanks